# How to draw an actual maltese cross?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

The symbol that is produced by the `\maltese` command is an [iron cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Cross),
not quite the same thing as a [maltese cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maltese_cross), 
both in terms of appearance and signification.

I was wondering if there was any way to draw an actual maltese cross in LaTeX as a math character.

Comment: It's been asked to be added to `Fontawesome` which has support in Xe/LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really seems that the unicode mapping is wrong in this place. The Maltese cross is indexed as [U+2720](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2720/index.htm). But the only font I could find to be mapping it right is the font [Code2000](http://www.fonts2u.com/code2000.font). It brings the following symbol:

[image]

The following MWE shows, how you can load just this symbol and proofs the scalability. It can be used in text and math:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{bbding} % for \CrossMaltese % results in a Koch Pattée which is to ugly to show
\usepackage{pifont} % for \ding{64}
\usepackage{MnSymbol} % for \MnMaltese
\let\MnMaltese\maltese
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand*{\amalfi}{\ensuremath{\text{\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"2720}}}}

\begin{document}
    {\Huge\amalfi}

    In text \amalfi{}, in in-line math $\amalfi$, and in a formula:
    \[\amalfi_{\amalfi_\amalfi}\]   
    \begin{tabular}{ll}\toprule
        Symbol&Example\\\midrule
        Iron Cross (Pattée)&$\maltese$\setmathfont{Asana Math}$\maltese$\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}$\maltese$\ding{64}$\MnMaltese$\setmainfont{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"2720}\\
        Pattée acc.\ Koch&\setmathfont{XITS-Math}$\maltese$\setmainfont{quivira.otf}\symbol{"2720}\setmainfont{DejaVuSans}\symbol{"2720}\\
        Maltese Cross&\amalfi\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Finally, I did some research about the "Maltese" crosses which exist. The following table shows the possible symbols. It does not contain a symbol from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) yet, but as Bernard mentioned in comment, there is a [feature request](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/3035) around. Hopefully, they will get it right.

[image]

---

**Edit**: shortest version for the Maltese Cross symbol

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\amalfi}{\ensuremath{\text{\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"2720}}}}

\begin{document}
    \amalfi
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks good. Could you just confirm what are the minimal set of packages needed to define your `\amalfi` command.

I guess `fontspec` and `unicode-math` at least maybe `mathtools` too? Thanks.

Comment: @Marc Please see my edit (at the very bottom). Glad you like it.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if you consider this a "math character" for your purpose, but you can draw a symbol with TikZ and scale it to the size of a symbol of your choice (the digit 0 in this case), so that it scales in math environments.

Also, I eyeballed the dimensions, so the lengths and angles are probably all wrong. Feel free to improve them. ;)

[image: Maltese cross in math mode]

Also works in text mode with different font sizes:

[image: Maltese cross in text mode]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newcommand{\maltcross}{\scalerel*{%
    \tikz\fill
    (0.02,0.02)    -- (0.2,0.5)   -- (0,0.4)  -- (-0.2,0.5)  --
    (-0.02,0.02)   -- (-0.5,0.2)  -- (-0.4,0) -- (-0.5,-0.2) --
    (-0.02,-0.02)  -- (-0.2,-0.5) -- (0,-0.4) -- (0.2,-0.5)  --
    (0.02,-0.02)   -- (0.5,-0.2)  -- (0.4,0)  -- (0.5,0.2)   --
    cycle;}% Scale this picture...
    {0}% ...to the size of this symbol.
}

\begin{document}
\[
    f(\maltcross, y) = 2^{\maltcross} \cdot 2^{3^{\maltcross}} + y\maltcross
    - \int\limits_{\maltcross}^{\maltcross+1} 9\maltcross
\]

\tiny \maltcross
\scriptsize \maltcross
\footnotesize \maltcross
\normalsize \maltcross
\large \maltcross
\Large \maltcross
\LARGE \maltcross
\Huge \maltcross
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of that `scalerel` magic, you could also use `em`  or `ex` as units in your drawing, because those units scale with the surrounding font size.

Comment: @Jake: Yes, I tried `\tikz[x=1em,y=1em]`, but that didn't scale when used as an exponent or subscript in math mode. Scaling in text mode worked however. For this purpose the `scalerel` also provides `\LMex` and `\LMpt` for the _local math_ units, but this approach seemed easier.

Comment: @Jake In math mode, em and ex retain the size of the base font size, whereas `scalerel` accounts for the math style you are in (e.g., `\scriptstyle`, `\scriptsciptstyle`).